# ActionScript 3: How to move a TextField smoothly?

Tags: actionscript-3, optimization, textfield, smooth-scrolling

In my program I have a feature of text scrolling across the screen. This works fine, except for the unbelievable laggy movement. I'm simply adding the speed to the x-position of the textfield, and the movement animation works fine for all other objects (movieclips, bitmaps etc).

EDIT:

I now tried to convert the text to a BitMap, and then move it. Unfortunately this resulted in the same "laggy" movement with lots of sudden "jumps".

```
bmd = new BitmapData (event_field.width, event_field.height, true, 0);
bmd.draw (event_field);

bm = new Bitmap (bmd);
bm.x = event_field.x;
bm.y = event_field.y;
bm.cacheAsBitmap = true;
bm.smoothing = true;
this.addChild(bm);
```

In my enter-frame-function:

```
bm.x-=3
```

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: can you also show how you do the animation? as maybe your laggy animation is due to the way you try to animate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not smoothing the textfield may improve performance, but using the native TextField class in my experience, has performance limitations that can't really be overcome.  Real-time rendering of text is expensive.  Real-time rendering that text to bitmapData, can also be expensive and is really only beneficial if the text doesn't change much.  In any case that's something `cacheAsBitmap` should already be doing automatically.

To overcome both of these issues, you should consider bitmap fonts.  These are pre-rendered, solving both of the above issues.  However, the native API doesn't support it.

The two options that I'm aware of:

1. [BMFontRenderer](https://github.com/bengarney/BMFontRenderer).  Some classes that supposedly provide support
   for bitmap font rendering.  I've not tried this so I can't vouch for
   it.
2. Use [Starling](https://gamua.com/starling/) for your whole project, which includes
   excellent support for bitmap fonts and distance field fonts
   (scalable bitmap fonts).  It's a 2D hardware accelerated framework,
   so this is just the tip of the iceberg in terms of what it can
   offer. I use it for everything now, but for your project it may be too late to be switching from the native framework to another.

To generate your bitmap fonts, these are some tools recommended by the [Starling Manual](http://manual.starling-framework.org/en/#_dynamic_text).  I personally use Littera and BMFont:

- [Littera](http://kvazars.com/littera/)
- [BMFont](http://www.angelcode.com/products/bmfont/)
- [Glyph Designer](https://www.71squared.com/glyphdesigner)
- [bmGlyph](https://www.bmglyph.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try embedding font or animate bitmap not textfield

- create snapshot of textfield before animation starts,
- hide textfield
- animate snapshot
- at animation finish move invisible textfield into destination, destroy snapshot and show textfield

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, this won't work, as the concept requires the text to change dynamically..

Comment: It will not work unless you try it:) Animated is Bitmap object which contains BitmaData and you can modify it while animating.

Comment: Okey. But how do I for instance create a "snapshot" of my textfield?

Comment: Using BitmapData's [draw](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#draw%28%29) function.

Comment: also to make it invisible you dont have to use visible or alpha properties, just remove it from stage:) it simplifies the drawing as you will not have to make it visible for drawing

Comment: I might be a bit stupid here...but I really don't understand how to convert my textfield to bitmap, and then be able to change the text later. I tried 'textField1.draw()', and that certainly didn't work. Could you please provide an example?:)

Comment: @user3257755 Don't forget to call `draw()` every single time you update the text field. Additionally, you can try increasing the framerate. 24fps, the default, is low for smooth animations. @Lukasz If you ever need to make an object visible again, it's actually best *not* to remove it from stage. Removing and adding to stage is a heavy operation in comparison to setting visibility. Definitely avoid setting alpha to 0, though, since the object would still be rendered, adding to frame construction time

Comment: Calling draw() returns "1061: Call to a possibly undefined method draw through a reference with static type flash.text:TextField."

Comment: I'll prepare an example later, for now I'll tell you that call draw not  on textfield but bitmapdata instance and pass textfield as argument of draw method.

Comment: I will be looking forward to your example :)

Comment: Ok, now I managed to draw it as bitmap and then move it. I'm still experiencing lots of sudden "jumps" in the animation of the text though.